# Interceptor in grails for CORS - GET works but not PUT, POST, DELETE

Tags: angular, grails3

Grails 3 war under tomcat, angular 2 running under nginx

I am using grails 3.2.0.M2. I have used the default controller from using the rest profile so essentially all of the code is in the UrlMappings.groovy file.

Here is the interceptor code

```
package heroes2
class HeroInterceptor {

    boolean before() {
        // header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8081" )
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        // response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://centos7-ansible")
        if (request.method == "OPTIONS") {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            // response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://centos7-ansible")
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600")
            response.status = 200
        }

        true
    }
```

Without the interceptor I was getting CORS error on GET. Now, GET now retrieves code. But POST, PUT and DELETE actions still show CORS error in the browser console.

Do I need to make other changes to the grails code for the plugin to cover actions other than GET?

Answer (score 0):

I have a gulp server on 8889 port for angular and the below interceptor works perfectly for ApiController with GRAILS 3.1.6.

```
class ApiInterceptor {

ApiInterceptor() {
  matchAll()
}

boolean before() {
  println "  Interceptor calling..."
  header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8889" )

  boolean options = ("OPTIONS" == request.method)
  if (options) {
    println "   OPTIONS case..."
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8889" )
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true" )
    header( "Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT")
    header( "Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600" )

    response.status = 200
  }

 true 
}

boolean after() { true }

}
```

I suggest to start some tests with an URL without * but with `localhost:yourport` and to insert some println inside the interceptor to check if option-branch-if is entered properly.

Comment: Hi Stefano, thanks for the help. But I still have the same problem of Cross Origin Request blocked when trying to POST. 
Interestingly, the prints are not appearing in the tomcat logs.

Comment: The lack of log prints suggests you are not entering the options part and so the interceptor is not allowing you POST, DELETE, PUT methods. So that is the key. I think you should investigate why your browser are not making pre-flight CORS OPTIONS request, Look [this] on browsers. (https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)